# XPS L502x with external DellST2210 24" LCD which won't play sound, while external ASUS VH242H 24" LCD will

Tags: windows-7, audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dell-xps

### MY CONFIGURATION

I have an XPS L502x hooked up to 2 external monitors:

1. Dell ST2210

   - connected via to my only HDMI port
   - no adapters on either end of the cable
   - HDMI cable from back of laptop to HDMI port on monitor
2. ASUS VH242H

   - connected via digital mini-display port (like on a Mac)
   - mini-port to HDMI adapter on the back of the laptop
   - HDMI cable from mini-port adaptor to HDMI port on monitor

in Volume Control Options or Sounds (Control Panel > Sounds), these 2 read as follows (notice the slight differences):

> **Dell ST2210**
>     2-Intel(R) Display Audio

and

> **ASUS VH242H-1**
>     2- NVIDIA High Definition Audio

---

### MY PROBLEM

1. Sounds will play on:

   - my laptop speakers perfectly well
   - my Asus VH242H, but it seems like it's only coming out of the right monitor speaker
2. Sounds will not play:

   - on my Dell ST2210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several different solutions, including new drivers for my DELL ST2210 LCD monitor.  But, in the end the only thing that worked was swapping out a $30 HDMI cable.